# How to generate repetitive permutations?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, iteration, combinations, permutation

I am trying to generate permutations with 2 strings in n digit. For example, I have 2 two types of string, "A" "B.". n is the string's total length. It always changes. Sometimes 5, 6, etc. I want to print all possible results with repetition. For Example,

if n=5
AAAAA
AAAAB
AAABB
AABBB
....
ABABA
....
BBBBB

My total combinations are 2^5=32.

if n=6
AAAAAA
AAAAAB
AAAABB
AAABBB
....
ABABAA
....
BBBBBB

My total combinations are 2^6=64.

How can I write this code in VB.net?

Comment: Please share with us how did you try to tackle your problem and where did you stuck.

Comment: With your values,  "A" "B", are they always unique?

Comment: Assuming they are, see [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26983642/2330053) for one possibility.

Comment: Before you try to print them out , I would get the number of possible permutations. Calculate this by hand.

Comment: Yes My values always are same, they never change Maybe later, new values can be added

Answer (score 0):

Using my `Revision` class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26983642/2330053):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Rev As New Revision("AB", "AAAAAA")
    Dim Length As Integer = Rev.CurrentRevision.Length

    Dim results As New List(Of String)
    While Rev.CurrentRevision.Length = Length
        results.Add(Rev.CurrentRevision)
        Rev.NextRevision()
    End While

    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.DataSource = results
End Sub
```

For bigger sets, definitely use some kind of threading as in my linked example!

I also highly recommend Adrian Akison's `Combinatorics` library [found here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there will be bigger sets, For example, 12 digits. So I am using this